# Can users added to certain OU automatically be member of particular group

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, groups, organizational-unit

Windows Server 2008 R2.

Can AD be set up so that any user added to a particular OU automatically be assigned to a particular user group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality to do this natively. You can have something like a PowerShell script called on a regular bases from Task Scheduler though.

You would use the `Get-ADUser` and `Add-GroupMember`, both of which are parts of the ActiveDirectory module for PowerShell that is part of RSAT.